# Performing one-loop "triangle" integral

Tags: homework-and-exercises, feynman-diagrams, perturbation-theory

Let's have integral
$$
\tag 1 I_{\alpha \beta \gamma \delta} = \int d^{4}qD^{V}_{\alpha \beta}(k + q)D^{V}_{\gamma \delta}(q + k - p)D^{f}(q),
$$
where $D^{V}_{\alpha \beta}$ corresponds to massive vector boson propagator, $D^{f}(q)$ corresponds to massless fermion propagator. This integral corresponds to triangle one-loop diagram.

Do you know some sources where there are methods of performing of integrals of type $(1)$? Especially I'm interested in explicit formula for $(1)$.

P.S. I know about different methods of calculation of loop integrals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the special case of Feynman's trick 
$$
\frac{1}{A_1 A_2} = \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\left[(1-x)A_1 + xA_2 \right]^2 }
$$
You have to use the generalized version
$$
\frac{1}{A_1 \ldots A_n} = (n-1)!\int_0^1 \delta(x_1+ \ldots x_n -1)\frac{dx_1 \ldots dx_n}{
\left[x_1 A_1 + \ldots x_n A_n\right]^n}
$$
for $n=3$

And the rest of the steps are pretty much similar to the usual one-loop correction to the photon propagator.

Comment: But there are also terms like
$$
\frac{1}{A_{1}A_{2}A_{3}A_{4}^{2}},
$$
which arise from longitudinal parts of vector boson propagators. This creates "mechanical" problem with performing of integral. That's why I've asked about completed formula for such integrals.

Comment: Where is $A_4$ coming from? you only have three internal propagators in the diagram

Comment: and by the way "completed formula" means giving you the answer for your homework

Comment: Longitudinal part of propagators contains $\frac{p_{\mu}p_{\nu}}{p^{2}}$ term. The denominator of this term provides $\frac{1}{A_{4}}$ multiplier. The power of this multiplier may be up to two because of two propagators. And, as I said, I don't want to compute the sets of these integrals directly, I need the final formula (as I wrote in the question).

Comment: Oh I assumed you are considering the SM massive bosons, and working in Unitary or Feynman gauage, but you're right in Landau gauge or a hypothetical theory of massive vector bosons you do have these two extra denomenators. But in any case they are not both equal, because the two propagators have different momenta. So you have to use the above formula for $n=5$

Comment: and I don't think you can find a canned "formula" somewhere, you have to do the integrals